# After installing/removing Xen, can't use KVM

Tags: installation, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm evaluating different virtualization solutions. I decided to go with KVM over Xen. Unfortunately, now I can't create any KVM virtual machines via libvirt.

> jonathanfisher@blockparty /usr/share/qemu $ sudo virt-install
>   --name=pfsense --arch=x86_64 --vcpus=3 --ram=1024 --os-type=unix --connect qemu:///system --virt-type kvm --hvm --accelerate --vnc --noautoconsole --keymap=us --os-type=unix --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/pfsense-disk1.qcow2 -w bridge:wan0 -w
>   bridge:lan0 -v --os-variant=freebsd7 --boot hd
>
> Starting install... ERROR    internal error Process exited while
>   reading console log output: char device redirected to /dev/pts/11
>   Could not open option rom 'pxe-ne2k_pci.rom': No such file or
>   directory Could not read keymap file: 'en-us'
>
> Domain installation does not appear to have been successful. If it
>   was, you can restart your domain by running:   virsh --connect
>   qemu:///system start pfsense otherwise, please restart your
>   installation.

What's funny is the files are present:

> jonathanfisher@blockparty /usr/share/qemu $ ls bios.bin  linuxboot.bin
>   pxe-e1000.rom     pxe-pcnet32.rom  pxe-virtio.rom  vapic.bin
>   vgabios-cirrus.bin  vgabios-stdvga.bin keymaps   multiboot.bin 
>   pxe-ne2k_isa.rom  pxe-rtl8139.rom  qemu-linaro     vgabios.bin 
>   vgabios-qxl.bin     vgabios-vmware.bin

I'm probably just missing a symlink somewhere... this can't be that hard to fix. Any ideas? Just need to be pointed in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what what was wrong, but this finally fixed it.

> sudo aptitude purge virtinst  virt-viewer python-libvirt  libvirt0
>   libvirt-bin

Then I went around /etc /usr/share /var/lib /var/log and cleaned up anything related to qemu, kvm, etc.

after that, I just reinstalled:

> sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst bridge-utils

And I was good to go.